# Need to hide a tooltip after a few seconds from tap on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's an anchor tag with a tooltip:

```
<a data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Sorry, pronunciation audio not available!">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-off pronounce">
    </span>
</a>
```

On desktop screens, the tooltip only appears when the anchor is hovered over or clicked and vanishes when the mouse pointer moves away from it. However, on mobile screens, the tooltip does appear when the anchor is tapped but then stays on forever. Is there any way to make it fade out after a set period *only on mobile devices*?

**UPDATE:** For what it's worth, my tooltip JS looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").tooltip({ selector: '[data-toggle=tooltip]' });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help you :

```
$('body').click(function(event){
    if (event.target.id != 'tooltip'){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#tooltip').tooltip('hide');
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

JS FIDDLE : https://jsfiddle.net/b2t27sg0/3/

Comment: This should have worked but somehow it didn't. Could it be because `tooltip` is not exactly an *id* in my case but rather a value of the `data-toggle` attribute? Please see the question, I have updated it with the JS of my tooltip.